# #VMware Workstation Bridged Networking , VM not able to communicate to the base machine

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, bridged

**In VMware workstation the virtual machine which is Bridged is not able to communicate to Base machine.**

the base machine is connected to Wi-Fi Router and getting the IP through DHCP.the Virtual Machine is bridged with the base machine LAN card , is also getting the DHCP IP.

**But the Virtual Machine is not able to reach to BASE machine (vice-versa) ??**

although the Virtual Machines that are bridged are communicating to each other but not to the BASE Machines(Physical Machine.)

Kindly share if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check VMWare Virtual Network Editor, and ensure that the bridged adapter (usually VMNet0) is bridged to the right physical network adapter. Sometimes 'Auto' may bridge it to other adapter that you don't want.

Please also ensure that the DHCP you are getting on the VM's is really coming from your router and that you are getting IP's on the VM's on the same subnet as the IP on your Host system (and router). If you see IP's on a different subnet you may have some other DHCP server on your LAN...

Also note that by default some OS's (including Windows) block ICMP traffic, then if you are trying to ping each other system to test it you may get no reply despite there is connectivity, in that case you may want to check firewall settings and allow incoming echo requests.